# Get the current time when the user comes out of an item in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a horizontal `ListView` which contains albums. I want the time when the user opens and closes the album. I am able to get the time when the album is opened , but i don't know how i can get the time when the user comes back to the `ListView`.

Here is my code,

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                try {

                    JsonObject = new ArrayList<JsonObjectClass>();
                    JsonObjectClass jsonData = new JsonObjectClass();
                    String dateTime = (String)getDateTime();

                    gps = new GPSTracker(MainPhotoAlbumActivity.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        jsonData.lattitue = latitude;
                        jsonData.longitude = longitude;
                        jsonData.album_opened = dateTime;
                        jsonData.license_key = new HomeActivity().licKey;

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                    albumNameForContent = thumbNails1.get(position).AlbumName
                            .substring(thumbNails1.get(position).AlbumName
                                    .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);


                    jsonData.album_name = albumNameForContent;

//code to display each image in the album..

}
```

Please let me know how can i get this done.. Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at the lifecycle of an fragment http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html or activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html then try to set some breakpoints in the calling methods and see, if they are called

Comment: No i am not calling other Activity or fragments from there..

Comment: And fragments? Show us more code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the time wen user closes the album. I implemented `onBackPressed()` in my `Activity`, so when ever user clicks back button (meaning he s exiting from the album) i take the current time.